# Very new to ARM assembly language. Can someone help me with this program?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

Write the following code in ARM assembly code(Raspberry Pi)

g=12, h=8, i=2, j=5;

f = (g + h) - (i + j);

Your program displays the message:

f = (g + h) – (i + j) = 13

Note that 13 should be calculated, not hardcoded

```
        .data
string: .ascii  "\n f = (g+h) - (i+j) = %d\n"
@Code Section
        .text
        .global main
        .extern printf
main:   ldr R0,12
        ldr R1,8
        ldr R2,2
        ldr R3,5
        add R4,R0,R1
        add R5,R2,R3
        sub R6,R4,R5
        bl printf
```

How do you display the message: f = (g + h) – (i + j) = 13 in ARM assembly. I know I did it wrong, that was my try. And when I complie, it said "Bad instruction"...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aklh.png)
Can anyone tell me how to fix my code and finish this program? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: printf() is a C library function. You may not call it in your assembly environment.

Even if printf() can be called, it expects the r0/r1/r2/r3 to obey the Arm AAPCS ( procedure call standard). Your R0/R1 may not be expected by printf().

Comment: Thank you! And what should I use to display the message " f = (g + h) – (i + j) = " 13?

Answer (score 0):

To load a constant into a register, try `ldr R0, =12`.  This should generate an immediate mov instruction when the constant can be encoded appropriately, which is the case for small numbers, so in this case you could also write `mov R0, #12`.  If the constant does not fit, the constant will be assembled into memory and a load instruction will be generated.

You'll also need to pay attention to what arguments `printf` expects and in what registers.  For starters, it needs a format string.

Comment: Thanks!! And how should I print the message " f = (g + h) – (i + j) = " 13?